# Answer Whatsapp video call from lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, video, settings, whatsapp.app

I would like to answer Whatsapp video calls from the lock screen. [Whatsapp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/voice-and-video-calls/how-to-make-a-video-call/?lang=en&_fb_noscript=1) and [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251402058) say it's possible and the default, but it doesn't work for me.

I can answer a voice call from Whatsapp or Signal with a slider at the bottom of the screen. But for a Whatsapp video call, a notification appears; swiping it left shows "Options", which brings Touch ID or the passcode. I cannot find any setting for this in the iPhone settings (under Touch ID & Passcode) or the Whatsapp settings. It's an iPhone 6 with iOS 12.5.4, but the same problem happens on iPhone 7 with iOS 15.0.1

Is it possible? If so, how to enable it?